# How do I get the count of black cells of 2D grid row by row?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently implementing a visualization of run length encoding using a 2d grid/array. You have the ability to click on the cells to get it black otherwise it remains white. Now I want to count the black cells row by row. For example let 'b' be black cells and 'w' be white cells

```
bbbbwwww -> 3b4w
wwwbbbbw -> 3w4b1w
bbbbbbbb -> 8b
wwwwwbbb -> 5w3b
```

Here is the code to generate the cells

```js
function generateGrid(rows, cols) {
  var grid = "<table>";
  for (row = 1; row <= rows; row++) {
    grid += "<tr>";
    for (col = 1; col <= cols; col++) {
      var cell = "<td> </td>";
      grid += cell;
    }
    grid += "</tr>";
  }
  $("#tableContainer").empty();
  $("#tableContainer").append(grid);
  $('td').click(function(){
    changeColor($(this))
  });
}
function changeColor(cell) {
  if(cell.hasClass('clicked')){
    cell.removeClass('clicked');
  } else {
  cell.addClass('clicked');
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <style>
        body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

#tableContainer {
  display: table;
  padding: 1px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: .5px;
  background-color: white;
  display: table-cell;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

td:hover {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

td.clicked {
  background-color: black;
}
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="a3.css">
<script src="a3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <!-- <input type = "button" id="bClick" onclick="myFunction()"> -->
  <h1>Run Length Encoding Demonstration</h1>
 
  Rows: <input type="number" name="Rows" value=4 min=0 id="Rows"><br> Columns: <input type="number" name="Columns" value=4 min=0 id="Columns"><br><br>

  <button onclick="generateGrid(document.getElementById('Rows').value, document.getElementById('Columns').value)"> Generate </button>
  <button onclick="reloadPage()">Reload Page</button>
  <textarea id="Solution" cols="110" rows="4" placeholder="Here will be the encoded image data"></textarea>



  <div id="tableContainer"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

I am new to javascript. But if we look closer to the black cells we see that they contain the class "clicked". I should loop over all td and check if they contain the class "clicked" and store the value in a counter variable. Will this approach be working?

Comment: You can use [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) in `changeColor` instead of checking for the class...

Comment: Also, if you want to know if an approach will work, arguably the best way to find out is to try it and see :).

Answer (score 1):

Well, the easy answer is: yes, that way it will work.

Simply use the `hasClass` method.

Another way I can think of, as each row is a `tr`, for each `tr` make a selector to select all `td` which have a `.clicked` class, and then count the result. Something like this: `trRow.find("td.clicked").length`. A non jQuery way to do this can be `trRow.querySelectorAll("td.clicked").length`.